# play services update required

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am making an android application using google maps. Using Android studio.

It tells me to add following line to my build.gradle.

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'`

However when I test the application on my phone and on genymotion emulator it tells me to update google play services. The problem is there is no update for Google Play Services available for my phone.
Both my newest phone, my old phone and my Genymotion emulator Nexus5 use Google Play Services version 5.0.89. This is the most recent version available on Google Play.
A fix for this was to use this line instead of the above.
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'`
It works perfectly on all my test devices.

My question is will this also work for phones using a newer version of of Google Play Services?
Should I do something so it uses the most recent version instead of 5.0.89? What about older devices?(note I am not currently using the support library)

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be a duplicate. Didn't see that one in my searches, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that 5.2.08 is [bugged](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880). Just use 5.0.89. I saw somewhere that 5.2.08 is only for Android L, but I can't find the source.

Comment: So using 5.0.89 is fine and will work on most devices?

Comment: As far as I know on all devices below API level 20, provided the latest version of Google Play Services is installed on the device.